# Excel VBA : Selecting Sheet based on the Drop down list name. Run time error 9 - Subscript out of range. Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the below line of code for navigating to sheet according to the Drop down list item selected.        It works for the first time But i get Run time error 9 - Subscript out of range Error, when i attempt to do for the next time.          I am getting error in the line
"ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cboDependentList.Value).Activate"

Below is the line of code:

```
'Populate dependent combo box with appropriate list items                                 
'according to selection in cboCategoryList.
Sub test()                                                   
    Dim rng As Range   
    Dim ws As Worksheet    
    Dim str As String     

    Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")     
    str = cboCategoryList.Value      
    Me.cboDependentList.Clear       

    On Error Resume Next         
    For Each rng In ws.Range(str)        
      Me.cboDependentList.AddItem rng.Value       
    Next rng         

End Sub

Sub cboDependentList_Change()        
      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cboDependentList.Value).Activate      
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()         
    'Populate combo box with inventory categories.         
    Dim rng As Range         
    Dim ws As Worksheet        

    Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")         
    Me.cboCategoryList.Clear        

    For Each rng In ws.Range("Category")         
      Me.cboCategoryList.AddItem rng.Value            
    Next rng                      

End Sub
```

Comment: did you try msgbox'ing the value before it gets activated? just put a

    msgbox(cboDependentList.value)

before the line where it shows error. Maybe there are spaces and that is why its showing an error.

Comment: Yes i did. Msgbox is displayed correctly as per the Listname. But after the msgbox, same Run time error is displayed

Answer (score 0):

At times the debugger of excel doesn't highlight the line of code that actually triggers the error, instead it highlights one of the callers (higher up in the call stack).

In this case the activate method might not directly be causing the Run time error 9 - Subscript out of range Error, but its effect in subroutine Worksheet_Activate might. I would advise you to set a breakpoint on the line calling Activate, and step through the code in debug mode. If that doesn't work you might have to set the breakpoint at the start of the subroutine Worksheet_Activate.